# Tabs work weared after setRoot

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am creating an Android app using ionic and angular4. I am setting root to nav in app component based on current login session. If the user is not logged in, it will set Login component as root and if the user session is available, it will set Dashboard component which has tabs.

**Everything works perfect** when a user is already logged in and Dashboard to root nav is set from app component.

When I logout and login, on login I am setting root for navCtrl, it is showing dashboard component, showing selected tabs but, the tab selection in tab bar and navigation bar is incorrect. When I select second tab, it is rendering component for second tab and highlighting first tab, showing name of first tab in navigation bar.

Here is what I am doing:

**app.component.ts**

```
  if (userLoggedIn()) {
    this.rootPage = DashboardComponent
  } else {
    this.rootPage = LoginComponent
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
onLogin(){
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(DashboardComponent)
}
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  template
})
export class DashboardComponent {
  suggestions: any = SuggestionsComponent
  advSearch: any = AdvancedSearchComponent
  favourite: any = FavouriteComponent
  settings: any = SettingsComponent

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Aayushyagathi</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-tabs color="primary">
    <ion-tab [root]="suggestions" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="advSearch" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="favourite" tabIcon="heart"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="settings" tabIcon="cog"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

I am missing something? Is there any other way to show dashboard after login?

**ionic-angular:** 3.7.1

**angular:** 4.4.5

Comment: you will have to show the ts file for DashboardComponent

Comment: @SurajRao, I updated question. Dashboard component works fine when the user is already logged in and the Dashboard as root is set from app.component.ts

Comment: not sure if it has anything to do with your issue.. use `ion-tabs` without `ion-header` and `ion-content`. They will be from the individual tabs

Comment: @SurajRao Kept only ion-tabs in dashboard. Removed ion-header and ion-content. But still same issue. :(

Comment: can you show the logout function?

Comment: @SurajRao, Logout not yet implemented. Stuck on login only :(

Comment: oh I mistook the flow.. you said _When I logout and login, on login I am setting root for navCtrl_

Comment: @SurajRao, yeah, I am just removing session from server side to implement logout for development. Even the functionality works perfect when I login and refresh the browser or close the app and start again.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong here.. maybe try setting navCtrl root as login page on logout